# Sending silently email when page loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I need to send an email(silently) each time page was loaded.
I tried below code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

var email = "h.kamrava@yahoo.com" 
var subject = "test" 
var body = "Hello world" 

document.write("<form name="form" action=\"mailto:"+ email +"\?subject="+ subject +"\&body="+ body +"\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"text/plain\"></form>") 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="document.form.submit()">
</body>
</html>
```

It's does't work to me! What am i doing wrong? tnx

Comment: JavaScript cannot send mail. Server side can and this is better because the user cannot see the contents of the email (unless they are the recipient). See here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mail.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you let the server do this, like [PHP mail](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php), rather than have JS do it. You can send a request to the server on page load to tell the server to send an email to your target. That way:

- No messy, creepy looking scripts on your page.
- They'll never know an email was actually sent.
- "Fire and forget". Send the request to the server, and done! The server does the rest.
- Your email address, written only on the server, stays hidden in the server side and avoid email harvesters and subsequently, spam.

The request that triggers it could be anything, like loading a 1x1 gif, a script, AJAX or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do the same through forms, especially a post form. In either case what you do won't be silent as it requires the user to send that email. mailto: simply presents the user with a way to send the email using their own client.

If you want to send an email quickly from your HTML document, use mailto: from within an anchor, then either wait for the user to click it or force it to click.

```
<a href="mailto:hello@world.com">My link</a>
```

If you can use PHP or some other server-side language, it'd be much easier and "silent". Check out the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function of PHP, which allows you to send an email to whoever from whoever.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ajax for this purpose .
for example you can use JQuery ajax , something like this :

```
$(document).load('ajax/mail.php?email=exp@mail.com&subject=test&body=hi')
```

and then in php page use mail() function to send it

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Looking at the form code, I can see that this won't actually send an email...but this would be how you would submit a form using javascript.  If you want to send an email silently, you will need to post to some backend service.

Try putting everything into a load handler:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 

function sendEmail(){
    var email = "h.kamrava@yahoo.com" 
    var subject = "test" 
    var body = "Hello world" 

    document.write("<form name="form" action=\"mailto:"+ email +"\?subject="+ subject +"\&body="+ body +"\" method=\"post\" enctype=\"text/plain\"></form>");
    document.form.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="sendEmail()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

checkout this :

http://jsfiddle.net/4gGFR/

and instead of calling form post, call that `<body onload="sendemail();">`